# Calculate the coordinates for secondaries on CIE chromacity diagram?

Tags: calculations

I'm trying to use this solution to calculate the secondary coordinates from primaries: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/75238/115749

But it won't work for any other primary than those in the solution (red and green).
The results are wrong.

Here is my adaption to work with colour 0.4.4:

```
import colour
import numpy as np
from colour.models import RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT709

# Conversion from RGB to chromaticity coordinates.
# Defining RGB values for reference.
RGB_r = np.array([1, 0, 0])
RGB_g = np.array([0, 1, 0])

# We assume they are encoded in *sRGB* colourspace.
XYZ_r = colour.RGB_to_XYZ(RGB_r,RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT709)
XYZ_g = colour.RGB_to_XYZ(RGB_g,RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT709)

# Conversion to chromaticity coordinates.
xy_r = colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_r)
print(xy_r)
# [ 0.64  0.33]

xy_g = colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_g) 
print(xy_g)
# [ 0.3  0.6]

# Conversion to CIE xyY in order to maintain Luminance ratios.
# Using sRGB Luminance ratios, second row of the NPM.
xyY_r = [xy_r[0], xy_r[1], colour.models.RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT709.matrix_RGB_to_XYZ[1, 0]]
xyY_g = [xy_g[0], xy_g[1], colour.models.RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT709.matrix_RGB_to_XYZ[1, 1]]
print(xyY_r)
print(xyY_g)

xy_s = colour.XYZ_to_xy(
    colour.RGB_to_XYZ(
        colour.XYZ_to_RGB(colour.xyY_to_XYZ(xyY_r),RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT709) +
        colour.XYZ_to_RGB(colour.xyY_to_XYZ(xyY_g),RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT709),RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT709))
print(xy_s)
```

So if I change here to any other primary the coordinates are wrong:

```
RGB_r = np.array([1, 0, 0])
RGB_g = np.array([0, 1, 0])
```

- Yellow ([1, 0, 0] + [0, 1, 0]) --> [ 0.419306  0.505257] correct
- Cyan ([0, 1, 0] + [0, 0, 1]) --> [ 0.15433113  0.07559207] not correct
- Magenta ([1, 0, 0] + [0, 0, 1]) --> [ 0.17513059  0.07384747] not correct

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the photography: https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RomeoNinov the link to the solution I used is on the same topic ...

Comment: I cannot vote to NOT close this question because apparently more than 15 years are needed to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very likely to me that the problem is with `xyY_r =`  and `xyY_g =` calculations. It's very obvious that it only works for finding yellow.
For other colours the subscripts of `RGB_to_XYZ_matrix` must be different.